# returning a zero from a mysql count even it there is no result for that month

Tags: mysql

i have a logs table that i want to show the details in a chart, so i wanted a query that will show all the records from January to the current month and if the activities in that month are zero, it should return zero so that the chart may flow,

may table looks like this:

```
id      user_id  action                 date_added
75      56      Base Adding            2017-02-29 11:52:35
76      56      Base Adding            2017-02-29 11:59:28
77      61      Fuel Adding            2017-02-29 12:05:16
78      56      Update details         2017-02-29 12:17:08
79      57      Logged In              2017-02-29 12:25:41
80      56      Base Adding            2017-03-29 12:40:56
81      55      Logged In              2017-02-29 12:51:31
82      56      Base Adding            2017-05-29 12:53:25
```

the results that i wanted top see is something like this:

```
MonthAdded         Totalcount
2017-01              0
2017-02              2
2017-03              1
2017-04              0
2017-05              1
```

My query looks like this and its not giving me the output, please help me.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y-%m') AS MonthAdded, COUNT(id) AS Totalcost FROM audit_log WHERE date_added LIKE '%2017%' AND user_id = '56' AND (action = 'Base Adding') GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y-%m') ASC
```

Comment: this is impossible.. you have more than 2 counts of this 2017-02.

Comment: the action for Base Adding are 2 for 2017-02

Comment: Do it a clear question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the details According to your sample data:

Detailed Result:

```
select  MonthAdded,count(date_substr) as cnt   from        
(select '2017-01'as MonthAdded  UNION all
select '2017-02' UNION all
select '2017-03'  UNION all
select '2017-04'  UNION all
select '2017-05' UNION all
select '2017-06'  UNION all
select '2017-07'  UNION all
select '2017-08'  UNION all
select '2017-09'  UNION all 
select '2017-10'  UNION all 
select '2017-11'  UNION all 
select '2017-12') as a

left join

(select id, user_id, action, date_added,SUBSTRING(date_added FROM 1 FOR 7) as date_substr from
(select 75 as id,      56 as user_id,     'Base Adding' action,            '2017-02-29 11:52:35' as date_added UNION all
select  76,      56,      'Base Adding',            '2017-02-29 11:59:28' UNION all
select 77,      61,      'Fuel Adding',            '2017-02-29 12:05:16' UNION all
select 78,      56,      'Update details' ,        '2017-02-29 12:17:08' UNION all
select 79,      57,      'Logged In' ,            '2017-02-29 12:25:41' UNION all
select 80,      56,      'Base Adding',           '2017-03-29 12:40:56' UNION all
select 81,      55,      'Logged In' ,            '2017-02-29 12:51:31' UNION all
select  82,      56,      'Base Adding',            '2017-05-29 12:53:25') as a
where action = 'Base Adding' and user_id = 56) as b

on a.MonthAdded = b.date_substr
group by MonthAdded
```

Final Query Structure:

```
select  MonthAdded,count(date_substr) as cnt   from        
(select '2017-01'as MonthAdded  UNION all
select '2017-02' UNION all
select '2017-03'  UNION all
select '2017-04'  UNION all
select '2017-05' UNION all
select '2017-06'  UNION all
select '2017-07'  UNION all
select '2017-08'  UNION all
select '2017-09'  UNION all 
select '2017-10'  UNION all 
select '2017-11'  UNION all 
select '2017-12') as a

left join

(select id, user_id, action, date_added,SUBSTRING(date_added FROM 1 FOR 7) as date_substr from
(select * from yourtable) as a
where action = 'Base Adding' and user_id = 56) as b

on a.MonthAdded = b.date_substr
group by MonthAdded
```

It include until Dec to make sure if you have a data on it.

Result:

```
2017-01 0
2017-02 2
2017-03 1
2017-04 0
2017-05 1
2017-06 0
2017-07 0
2017-08 0
2017-09 0
2017-10 0
2017-11 0
2017-12 0
```

Comment: thank @reds the query worked like magic... just one more thing what does this line of the query do SUBSTRING(date_added FROM 1 FOR 7)

Comment: it is a function that getting a letter from any value from 1 to 7  like this "2017-12" it has a length of 7 characters

Comment: is it the same as doing DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y-%m')?

Comment: No it's not.. date_format is just refer only for dates.. but SUBSTRING is for all text even integer, even spaces....

Comment: Next time if you have some question make it clear so that the reader does not hesitate to have their answers if they can..

Comment: Hello, @reds, am getting this error when I run the query in my server. " Illigal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci, COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci, IMPLICIT) for operations  `=' ".  How do I solve it please, thanks

Comment: change "SUBSTRING(date(date_added) FROM 1 FOR 7)" and CAST(MonthAdded AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)

Comment: I have do e this: select id, user_id, action, date_added, CAST(MonthAdded AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) as date_substr ...,........... And its not wotki g yet. Would you mind modifying the answer I see it please

Comment: change this also "where cast(action AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)  = 'Base Adding' and cast(user_id AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) = '56')"

Comment: Give me 30mins I get to the office bro. Am In a small traffic 